# NSIS : How to cleanup the files on abort installation?

Tags: nsis

I have  written an NSIS script with the `!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT _onUserAbort` abort call. Inside the `_onUserAbort` function I want to remove some files.

Here's my function:

```
Function _onUserAbort
    MessageBox MB_YESNO "Are you sure you want to abort the installation?" IDYES true IDNO false
    true:
        ;cleanup function
        Abort
    false:
FunctionEnd
```

If i click on “Yes” it does nothing, but if I click on “No” it aborts the installation. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern UI already comes with an abort warning, there is no need to replicate this feature. To enable the warning, all you have to do is to define `MUI_ABORTWARNING`. You can further customize the warning with `MUI_ABORTWARNING_TEXT` and `MUI_ABORTWARNING_CANCEL_DEFAULT` (see [the documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html) for details!)

The `_onUserAbort` function is meant to run, when the user has *already decided* to abort installation. In your case, this should only handle the clean-up of files.